# I'm getting this error message: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` and was hoping someone could point out what's causing it

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, create-table

Here's the code that's causing the issue:

```
DROP TABLE customers;

--1 create tables
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id NUMBER(10),
  last_name VARCHAR2(25),
  first_name VARCHAR2(25), 
  home_phone VARCHAR2(12),
  address VARCHAR2(100),
  city VARCHAR2(30),
  state VARCHAR2(2),
  email VARCHAR2(25),
  cell_phone VARCHAR2(12),
  CONSTRAINT pk_customer_customer_id PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_last_name NOT NULL (last_name),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_first_name NOT NULL (first_name),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_home_phone NOT NULL (home_phone), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_address NOT NULL (address), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_city NOT NULL (city), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_state NOT NULL (state)
);
```

I've tried formatting the constraints at the column level and that didn't seem to help. I'm an absolute beginner and am doing this for a class so I'm sure it's something simple and silly but I couldn't figure it out for the life of me. After a few hours of frustration I figured I'd see if there was someone out there who could point me in the right direction.

I am using Oracle APEX.

Comment: What is your database ? MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle ? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: Varchar2 = probably Oracle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT NULL` constraints are defined in-line; there is no option to define them out-of-line (apart from using a `CHECK` constraint).

From the [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> #### `inline_constraint::=`
>
> [image: inline constraint syntax]
>
> #### `out_of_line_constraint::=`
>
> [image: out-of-line constraint syntax]

Therefore, if you want to use a `NOT NULL` constraint then you need to declare it inline:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id NUMBER(10),
  last_name   VARCHAR2(25)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_last_name NOT NULL,
  first_name  VARCHAR2(25)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_first_name NOT NULL, 
  home_phone  VARCHAR2(12)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_home_phone NOT NULL,
  address     VARCHAR2(100)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_address NOT NULL,
  city        VARCHAR2(30)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_city NOT NULL,
  state       VARCHAR2(2)
              CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_state NOT NULL,
  email       VARCHAR2(25),
  cell_phone  VARCHAR2(12),
  CONSTRAINT pk_customer_customer_id PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you are defining the `NOT NULL` constraints, they can be `CHECK` constraints so you should use:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id NUMBER(10),
  last_name VARCHAR2(25),
  first_name VARCHAR2(25), 
  home_phone VARCHAR2(12),
  address VARCHAR2(100),
  city VARCHAR2(30),
  state VARCHAR2(2),
  email VARCHAR2(25),
  cell_phone VARCHAR2(12),
  CONSTRAINT pk_customer_customer_id PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_last_name CHECK (last_name IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_first_name CHECK (first_name IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_home_phone CHECK (home_phone IS NOT NULL), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_address CHECK (address IS NOT NULL), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_city CHECK (city IS NOT NULL), 
  CONSTRAINT not_null_customer_state CHECK (state IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Comment: Your statement outputs `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` as you are missing the `IS` keyword from every `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Thanks @MT0 . Fixed it. The docs states `constraint name check ( condition )` :)

Comment: The documentation for conditions is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Conditions.html#GUID-C2E3ED44-16E7-4924-9125-E1693B1022A8) and specifically for `NULL` conditions is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Null-Conditions.html#GUID-657F2BA6-5687-4A00-8C2F-57515FD2DAEB).